# File not found from Python although file exists

Tags: python, file-io

I'm trying to load a simple text file with an array of numbers into Python. A MWE is

```
import numpy as np

BASE_FOLDER = 'C:\\path\\'
BASE_NAME = 'DATA.txt'
fname = BASE_FOLDER + BASE_NAME 

data = np.loadtxt(fname)
```

However, this gives an error while running:

```
OSError: C:\path\DATA.txt not found.
```

I'm using VSCode, so in the debug window the link to the path is clickable. And, of course, if I click it the file opens normally, so this tells me that the path is correct.

Also, if I do `print(fname)`, VSCode also gives me a valid path.

Is there anything I'm missing?

## EDIT

As per your (very helpful for future reference) comments, I've changed my code using the `os` module and raw strings:

```
BASE_FOLDER = r'C:\path_to_folder'
BASE_NAME = r'filename_DATA.txt'
fname = os.path.join(BASE_FOLDER, BASE_NAME)
```

Still results in error.

## Second EDIT

I've tried again with another file. Very basic path and filename

```
BASE_FOLDER = r'Z:\Data\Enzo\Waste_Code'
BASE_NAME = r'run3b.txt'
```

And again, I get the same error.
If I try an alternative approach,

```
os.chdir(BASE_FOLDER)
a = os.listdir()
```

then select the right file,

```
fname = a[1]
```

I still get the error when trying to import it. Even though I'm retrieving it directly from `listdir`.

```
>> os.path.isfile(a[1])
False
```

Comment: Is it an issue with case? I think it should still open it though.

Comment: Try with `os.path`

Comment: Have you tried to simply `open(fname)` and read from it?

Comment: Try to use _raw_ strings when working with files.

Comment: @MichaelButscher using the `os` module tells me that Python can't find the path at all. Though VSCode can...

Answer (score 5):

Using the module `os` you can check the existence of the file within python by running

```
import os
os.path.isfile(fname)
```

If it returns `False`, that means that your file doesn't exist in the specified fname. If it returns `True`, it should be read by `np.loadtxt()`.

*Extra: good practice working with files and paths*

When working with files it is advisable to use the amazing functionality built in the Base Library, specifically the module `os`. Where `os.path.join()` will take care of the joins no matter the operating system you are using.

```
fname = os.path.join(BASE_FOLDER, BASE_NAME)
```

In addition it is advisable to use raw strings by adding an `r` to the beginning of the string. This will be less tedious when writing paths, as it allows you to copy-paste from the navigation bar. It will be something like `BASE_FOLDER = r'C:\path'`. Note that you don't need to add the latest '\' as `os.path.join` takes care of it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've updated my code accordingly. Unfortunately it still gives me that error. `os.path.isfile(fname)` returns `False`, but the error is the same and the path in the error string is still clickable and active.

Comment: In my answer I assumed that `path` is a variable that stores the actual path to where the file is located. You should check that is pointing to the correct folder.

Comment: Just before `os.path.isfile(fname)` I'm running a `print(fname)`. This gives me a path (absolute path, not relative) in the terminal, which is clickable from VSCode. If I click there, the file opens, so I assume the path is correct.

Comment: Unfortunately the exact path contains confidential information itself. I have tried moving the file, though, and it still gives me error. However, if I call the actual filename `DATA.txt` (The original filenames contain underscores), then the program works. Is there a problem with underscores in filenames?

Comment: does the original filename have the format `_Data.txt`?

Comment: It's formatted like `SOMEINFO_SOMEOTHERINFO_DATA.txt`

Comment: Getting out of ideas here. Does the filename contains the `.txt` extension?  Can you please try to do `os.listdir(BASE_FOLDER)` and see if the file is among the retrieved file names? (If it is there try to use the output name of this function as BASE_NAME)

Comment: The file appears as output of `filelist = os.listdir(BASE_FOLDER)`. I then tried to do `BASE_NAME = filelist[2]`, but it gives me error again! What a mystery...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169688/discussion-between-gonzalo-mr-and-enzo).

Answer (score 1):

You may not have the full permission to read the downloaded file. Use

```
sudo chmod -R a+rwx file_name.txt
```

in the command prompt to give yourself permission to read if you are using Ubuntu.

Comment: I have full access to the file. I've created it and it has been working until a few hours ago. I'm under Windows, but I've checked the file properties and I indeed have full permission to the file. Moreover, the problem really is that Python does not "see" the file even though it lists it (see last edit). So it's not a matter of permissions.

Comment: also, if you are running the script in your base folder, you don't really need the base folder in your path. like `data = np.loadtxt(BASE_NAME)`

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that I was using the Linux home symbol in the link `(~/path/file)`. Replacing it with the absolute path `/home/user/etc_path/file` worked like charm.

Answer (score 0):

Python interpreter checking the path from which path is there in command prompt  while running

like example below

C:/Desktop/python_codes>python code.py

is differ from

C:/Desktop>python "python_codes\code.py"