# File not found error altough file does not exist

Tags: python-3.x, linux, file-not-found

I am trying to read through a file using the with open () function from python. I hand in the filepath via a base path and then a relative path adding on it:

```
filepath = base_path + path_to_specific_file

with open (filepath) as l:
    do_stuff()
```

base_path is using the linux home symbol ( I am using Ubuntu on a VM) `~/base_path/` since I want to have the filepath adapted on every device instead of hardcoding it.

This does not work. When I execute the code, it throws a file not found error, although the path exists. I even can open it by clicking the path in the vscode terminal.

According to this thread:

[File not found from Python although file exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50000399/file-not-found-from-python-although-file-exists)

the problem is the `~/` instead of `/home/username/`. Is there a way to replace this to have it working on every device with the correct path? I cannot comment yet on this thread since I do not have enough reputation, therefore I needed to create this new question. Sorry about that.

Comment: Do not concatenate file paths using `+`, as it can go wrong sometimes. use `pathlib.Path` and create your file path. You can get an `absolute_path()` from it which will resolve such forms

Comment: ~ is a shell shortcut.  use  path.home()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `expanduser()` from `pathlib` for this. Example

```
import pathlib
filepath = pathlib.Path(base_path) / path_to_specific_file
filepath = filepath.expanduser() # expand ~

with open(filepath) as l:
    do_stuff()
```

This should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can join paths e.g. with:

```
filepath = '/'.join((basepath, path_to_specific_file))
```

Or do as Kris suggested: use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html):

```
>>> basepath = Path('/tmp/')
>>> path_to_specific_file = Path('test')
>>> filepath = basepath / path_to_specific_file
>>> print(filepath)
/tmp/test
```

EDIT:

To access `$HOME` (`~`) you can use `Path.home()`.

Comment: This will not work for shortcut paths like ~.